# Hibernate Design question

Tags: hibernate

I have new to Hibernate! I wanted to inquire why do we normally have a service layer for hibernate. I mean if there are the DAOs, why do we need the service layers also?

Comment: Are you asking, why at your company do you always have service layers with hibernate? Or in general?

Answer (score 1):

I use a separate layer to handle units-of-work/transactions.  My DAOs are all quite simplistic and only handle straight database access.  Often a single task will involve several DAO interactions, but be in a single transaction (update several tables, retrieve data and conditionally update, etc).  By moving up a layer I can throw a @Transactional annotation on the task (assuming we're using Spring, but the concept holds without) and further encapsulate it.